# Using a Lyapunov function to determine stability of equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

> Given
>
> $$\left\{\begin{aligned} x' &= -x^3 + 7xy^2\\
> y' &= -3x^2y+y^3\end{aligned}\right.$$
>
> find $a, b > 0$ such that $L(x,y) = a x^2 + b y^2$ obeys $\frac{d}{dt}L \neq 0$ whenever $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. State whether the origin is a stable or unstable equilibrium.

So we want to find $a,b$ where $L(x,y)$ is a Lyapunov function, and then determine the stability of the equilibria.

First differentiate: $\frac{dL}{dt}=2axx'+2byy'$

Now plug in system: $2ax(-x^3+7xy^2)+2by(-3x^2y+y^3)$

By checking the equilibria, we see that both $x'$ and $y'$ equal zero only when $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Therefore we need to find when $2ax(-x^3+7xy^2)= -2by(-3x^2y+y^3)$

This is where I am confused, as I am not sure how to find $a$ or $b$ purely in terms of $x,y$ and what restrictions I may need to impose. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Long bet : Polar Coordinates

Comment: I tried that, and it got pretty messy. I am terrible at simplifying though, so I may be missing something obvious, but I did not see any direct simplifications.

Comment: Try the reduction method if polars didn't work (sorry can't check it explicitly atm I am via mobile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete the square in 
$$
\dot L=2(-ax^4+(7a-3b)x^2y^2+by^4)=\frac1{2a}\left(-(2ax^2-(7a-3b)y^2)^2+(4ab+(7a-3b)^2)y^4\right).
$$
This means that there will always be points in any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ with positive and negative signs of this type of Lyapunov function.

Checking with Wolfram alpha

```
streamplot[{-x^3+7xy^2,-3x^2y+y^3}, {x,-12,12}, {y,-9,9}]
```

confirms the saddle point behavior in the plot

[image]

Comment: Am I the only one who despises the notation $\dot L$?

Comment: And what does the double eigenvalue zero tell us? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: $\dot L$ or $\dot V$ is usually defined as $\nabla V(\vec x)\cdot f(\vec x)$, as the chain rule and insertion of the ODE prescribes. It is just one of many more or less strange abbreviations.

Comment: My apologies. Next time, I will spend a couple of seconds computing the Jacobian before asking a stupid question. Personally, I much prefer $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} (L \circ \mathbf x)$, but in this case one cannot use it, for the state vector is not denoted by $\mathbf x$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's a non-hyperbolic critical point with four elliptic sectors (only the trajectories starting on the $y$-axis do not converge to the origin), topologically it's not a saddle.